# Show the Schatten norm inequality $\left\| \boldsymbol{v} \right\| _{2/3}^{2}\ge \left\| \boldsymbol{v} \right\| _{1}^{3}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, matrix-norms

I want to show the following inequality
$$
\left\| \boldsymbol{v} \right\| _{2/3}^{2}\ge \left\| \boldsymbol{v} \right\| _{1}^{3} \tag 1
$$
where the norm is defined as $\left\| \boldsymbol{v} \right\| _p \equiv \left[ \sum_k{\left| v_k \right|^p} \right] ^{1/p}$ and $\boldsymbol{v}$ is a vector which can satisfy $\left\| \boldsymbol{v} \right\| _2=1$ if this condition is necessary to show the eq(1).

I've tried to use [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) for [Schatten norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_norm) but failed. I wonder if I missed something or should I use other inequality? But the Hölder's inequality is the only inequality I am familiar with for the Schatten norm.

Some more information about Hölder's inequality can be found in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1648542/proving-holders-inequality-for-schatten-norms).

Comment: This is not a Schatten norm.  And based on your definition of $\left\| \boldsymbol{v} \right\| _p \equiv \left[ \sum_k{\left| v_k \right|^p} \right] ^{1/p}$ for $p \in (0, 1)$ (in particular $p=\frac{2}{3}$) this is not even a norm -- check triangle inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually we don't need such complex inequalities. Instead, we only need to prove it by definition. By definition, we have
$$
\left\| \boldsymbol{v} \right\| _{2/3}^{2}=\left( \sum_k{\left| v_k \right|^{\frac{2}{3}}} \right) ^3
\\
\left\| \boldsymbol{v} \right\| _{1}^{3}=\left( \sum_k{\left| v_k \right|} \right) ^3
$$
Hence we only need to show
$$
\sum_k{\left| v_k \right|^{\frac{2}{3}}}\ge \sum_k{\left| v_k \right|}
$$
Using the fact that $\left\| \boldsymbol{v} \right\| _2=1$, we have $\left| v_k \right|\le 1,\forall k$ hence $\left| v_k \right|^{\frac{2}{3}}\ge \left| v_k \right|,\forall k$ which completes the proof.